# Other Ways of Create Element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create a code editor, and I have gotten this far.

```
<p>Quick Tips: This is entirely HTML, so when working with javascript use ＜script＞ tags.<p>
<button onclick="runcode()">Run Code</button>
<br>
<textarea id="textarea" class:".lined" rows:"5" style="resize: none;" autofocus></textarea>
<script>
window.onerror = function(error) {
  // do something clever here
  alert("ERROR"); 
};
 function renderLineNumbers(element, settings) {
    element = $(element);

    var linesDiv = element.parent().find('.numberedtextarea-line-numbers');
    var count = element.val().split("\n").length;
    var paddingBottom = parseFloat(element.css('padding-bottom'));
    var j = 0;

    linesDiv.find('.numberedtextarea-number').remove();

    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      if (settings.labels && j == settings.labels.length) {
        j = 0;
      }
      var lineLabel = settings.labels ? settings.labels[j] : i;
      var line = $('<div class="numberedtextarea-number numberedtextarea-number-' + i + '">' + lineLabel + '</div>').appendTo(linesDiv);
      j++;

      if (i === count) {
        line.css('margin-bottom', paddingBottom + 'px');
      }
    }
  }

var asdf = document.getElementById('textarea');
function runcode() {
    console.log(document.createElement(asdf.value))
}
</script>
<style> 
textarea{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

My text input: `<p>asdf</p>` returns the error: 
[image]

Is there any way I can fix this?
like another way to create an element using raw code?

Comment: `.createElement` expects a tag name, not a HTML string, as an argument.

Comment: You're trying to createElement with the value of the textarea , if you are trying to create another textarea tag you should just write document.createElement('textarea')

Comment: If you want to insert elements into the DOM based on arbitrary HTML, check out `Element.insertAdjacentHTML`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tagname in a createElement statement. You could do this:

```js
const ta = document.getElementById("ta")

function runcode() {
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.innerHTML = ta.value;
  console.log(div.innerHTML); // rendered
  console.log(div.firstElementChild); // other notation
}
runcode()
```

```html
<textarea id="ta"><p>Test a <span>span</span></p></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for createElement. As Teemu pointed out in his comment, createElement expects a tag. You can go about it like this (Example taken from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)):

```
var p = document.createElement("p");          // Create a <p> element
p.innerHTML = "asdf";                         // Insert text
console.log(p);                               // Print the tag

// If you want to append the tag to the page:
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: the issue is that the textarea contains a complete html string